# Playing and cutting video using Java

Tags: java, video

I'm writing a Video catalog system and I was wondering if its possible to first, open a video in my application (needs to be a wide variety of formats), and second, allow users to cut the video at a given time-stamp.

If this isn't something that can be done easily, then is it possible to open a video using an existing program on the machine through java?

### EDIT

After a little research I found I could use the java Desktop API open open files with their default program.  Due to the fact that the program needs to be able to work with a wide variety of format (including footage from RED camera), I've decided to go down this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part you might have a look at [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/).

Comment: any idea what formats vlcj supports?  I looked on the site and was unable to find any info

Comment: vlcj is a binding for the VLC player which supports "a few" formats: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Java Media Framework (JMF). It is very powerful although you have to spend some time to learn the basic concepts before you are starting coding.

Comment: I looked at JMF but it seems out of date (last api update in 1999)